# C# Sessions SaveOrUpdate not working

Tags: c#, session, transactions, insert-update

I'm trying to update a database using the Session lybrary and transactions. I have a function that does some work on objects and then updates the DB. Here is my code:

```
using (_session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    _session.SaveOrUpdate(foo);
                    _session.Transaction.CommitAsync();
                }
```

`foo` is the object i'm trying to update. Now the thing is I call this function more than once using a for loop and the database gets updated only the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I'm not really sure what was the problem the only thing i did differently was retriving all objects first before start saving them back.